# Android: Menu on a ListView row

Tags: android, android-listview

In the Google Play Store search, each row has a menu button which opens a system style menu. I want to achieve this same effect in my app. How do I show a menu from a button?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. In the OnClickListener for my button I use PopupMenu.

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        PopupMenu pm = new PopupMenu(_context, view);
        Menu menu = pm.getMenu();
        // here you could use a menu inflater to use a menu resource xml
        menu.add("One");
        menu.add("Two");
        pm.show();
    }
```

I just didn't figure out the magic google search terms until after I asked the question.

Comment: Very nice. But what about on click listeners for those items?

Comment: PopupMenu has its own listener: `pm.setOnMenuItemClickListener(...)`

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a "Menu item selection".

Following: http://www.intertech.com/Blog/android-menu-selection/

Answer (score 0):

I used the [ListPopupWindow](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListPopupWindow.html) to achieve the same thing and it also part of the compatibility package. The object has same constraints. You have to specify an anchor view, that could be the button you pressed on, and you have to specify a width. Take a look in particaluar to `setAnchorView` and `setContentWidth`. On the other hand, imo, the fact that you have to use an adapter, allows you a high level of customization at the UI level